# Grabbing multiple matched strings using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I’m creating a program that grabs all names in a given document with the below regex.

```
string pattern = @"(?<=Name)[\s](.*?)[\s]";
```

However this regex will not work if the document has name in it but used in a different context. Hence I modified my code below.

```
string pattern @"(?<=Name:[\s])(.*?)[\s]";
```

However even though this regex works, it only runs once and outputs the first name it finds unlike the first regex shown

Edited
———
Document has a series of names like 
Name: John
Name: Jane 
Name: Mary

There will be a sentences below but with the word name being used, what I want is just for the Words after Name: to be grabbed throughout the document.

What I used to trigger the output is:

```
 If (MatchesPattern.success)
  { 
   RegexWriter(pattern.value, fileName)

  }
```

Comment: your regular expression seems to be right, can you post the code that you're using to capture the results?

Comment: @rm.szc81 regex writer is a function I wrote to do the stream read and write. It seems to be working fine with the first code

Comment: You have to loop through the matches to get all of them. You might omit the capturing group `(?<=\bName: )\S+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess,

```
^Name:\s*(\S+)\s*$
```

might work.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^Name:\s*(\S+)\s*$";
        string input = @"Name: John
Name: Jane  
Name: Mary 

a sentence here with name in it would be fine. ";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/5Q3jU1)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UxGl4G/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/UxGl4G/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Emma, I’ll take a look! Appreciate it a lot ((:

Answer (score 0):

@Emma has smashed this, I just want to point out that 
[Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8), in the [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8#examples) section which

> uses a regular expression to check for repeated occurrences of words in a string.

While it doesn't do what you're after it shows how to interact with groups, which may or may not be useful for you :)

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
            GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeated at positions {1} and {2}",  
                              groups["word"].Value, 
                              groups[0].Index, 
                              groups[1].Index);
}
```